# Alias definition gives error "is not a member of std"

Tags: c++

I have an enumerator `SomeThing` declared in namespace with the same name in `SomeThing.h`.

```
namespace SomeThing{
   enum SomeThing{
      own            =  0,
      a              =  1, 
      b              =  2, 
      c              =  3, 
      d              =  4, 
      i              =  5, 
      j              =  6, 
      k              =  7, 
      l              =  8,
      omk            =  9,  
      ck            = 10, 
      central        = 14, 
      neutral        = 15, 
      m              = 18, 
      n              = 19, 
      o              = 20, 
      p              = 21, 
      q              = 22, 
      r              = 23, 
      s              = 24, 
      t              = 25,
      g              = 26,
      ck2            = 27,
      ha             = 28,
      hf             = 29
   };
}
```

Some of the enums are set with aliases with the following code.

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_LOGIC_H
#define SOMETHING_LOGIC_H
#define mml omk
#define tri ck
#define next central
#define y neutral
#define HF hf
#include "SomeThing.h"
#endif
```

But whenever I try to build I get the error `'central' is not a member of 'std' in "#define next central"`. However, when I try to build with the line `#define next central` commented out, it builds correctly. It's unclear why it should give this error as `central` is clearly a member of the enum SomeThing.

Any idea why this sort of error could happen when setting a simple alias?

I should mention that I'm using Qt Creator as IDE, I don't know if it makes any difference.

Comment: Probably something elsewhere in your code is using [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).  That's what happens when you use macros to redefine words that already mean something else.

Comment: There's a function `std::next`. Don't use macros

Comment: Why use a macro for this? `central = 14, next = central`. Or if it's not your enum, a regular constant should suffice; you can still give it the proper type.

Comment: Macros are evil.  The C Preprocessor is The Devil™.

Answer (score 2):

Macros are a direct substitution system. Use a `constexpr` variable instead, as it is basically identical without this issue.

```
constexpr auto next = central;
```

Somewhere in your code, you use `std::next`, and it substitutes the `next` to `central`. It then becomes `std::central`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

That shows why macros should never be used. When you

```
#define next central
```

you also end up modify the code in some header for `std::next`, as a result, the code for `std::next` breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Compare

> `'central' is not a member of 'std' [...]`

to

> [...] as `central` is clearly a member of the enum SomeThing.

You have failed to establish a counter to the error message. The identifier `central` can be a member of an enum while simultaneously not being a member of an unrelated namespace.

When dealing with macros, it sometimes helps to <del>run away</del> reverse the substitution in error messages. The compiler complained that `central` is not a member of `std`, but try reading that as `next` is not a member of `std`. Then go see if [`next` is a member of `std`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next). This reveals that some code affected by the macro definition tries to use `std::next` but your macro broke that by changing it to `std::central`.

The capability of namespaces to avoid name conflicts is subverted by the use of macros. To get an alias that plays nice with other code, use a constant.

```
// The name qualifications might vary depending on the context.
constexpr SomeThing::SomeThing next = SomeThing::central;
```